# Storing program settings in Java

Tags: java

i am developing a java application. I've got a txt file such like this:

```
Component(Journal, Account, AnalysisCodes...):
Journal
*****
Method(Query, Import, CreateOrAmend...):
Import
*****
Username:
PKP
*****
Password:
test
*****
Host:
localhost
*****
Port:
8080
*****
Program's path:
C:/Connect Manager/
*****
XML Name:
ledger.xml
*****
```

This java program does not write anything in this file, it just reads it. However i could not figure out where to store this txt file. Path must be same for every users since it is hard coded inside. I cannot read path of the program if i don't know the path of program.

Here is my code:

```
String lineconfig="";
String pathconfig= "C:/Connect Manager/" + "config.txt";
BufferedReader readerconfig= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathconfig));
while((lineconfig=readerconfig.readLine())!=null)
{
    stringList.add(lineconfig);
}
readerconfig.close();
```

As you see, i need an exact location for *pathconfig*.

Sorry if i caused any confusion in question. I would appreciate your suggestions.

Besides that:
Another program should be able to edit this or the user. I will make this program a jar.

Comment: Put this file in your project and set `pathconfig` just as `config.txt`.

Comment: `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("config.txt");` then put it in same level as your class. Or, you could use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: Not directly related to the question but might be though useful for the OP: Have a look at [Property Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use a **properties file**. It is better to read and it is easier for the user to configure the properties. Look at this [**short tutorial**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) for an explanation of the `.properties` file. To read and write values from and to the file follow this [**short tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

Have you tried **using**:

```
path = "config.txt"
```

If you use this syntax you should get the file in the **same directory as the jar**. Keep in mind that you can use the shortcuts ".." and "." to go to a directory.

With `..` you go to the directory above.

With `.` you get your actual directory.

Comment: It looks like this tutorial is going to work. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Your welcome ^^ Look at the update with the definitions of how to use the propertie file and the tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use properties and you can place them in your `res` folder. Check out [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) for more.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
          //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
          prop.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");));

          //get the property value and print it out
          System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
          System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
          System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The `res` folder is part of your project, so it's (somehow) always in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look at the Java Preferences API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html